# Partial Logout of some users in JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter

I have this workflow

- Login (Once)
- Create Orders (in a loop for x mins)
- Logout (Once)

Please let me know how can I achieve the below workload in JMeter:

- Log in all the users -group 1- (say 10 users ). Keep on creating Orders.
- Log in another set of users -group 2- (say 10 users, after 15 mins of the test). Keep on creating orders.
- Log out all group 1, [Lets say after 45 mins of the test].
- Logout group 2 [At the end of the test, let's say after 1 hr.]

Note: Main focus of the test is to logout the first 10 users and keep the next 10 users running till the end of test.

Edit 1: Removed "Stay Logged in" to avoid confusion. Threads should keep on creating orders until they log out.

Comment: I don't see the capability of a nested thread group which would satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "stay logged in"? If user doesn't send any [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) to the server it doesn't produce any load so it doesn't make any sense to "stay logged in" unless it is connected with some network footprint which you need to mimic.

Most probably when you log into the application you're getting a [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) which has [Expires](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.1) attribute so when you make the next request it checks whether your session is expired and if it's not - you're still "logged in", if it is - you will be redirected to the login page.

If you still want to implement your weird use case you can add a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) as a child of the Logout request and configure the "sleep" time there.

If there is some background network activity (like some information on the page is refreshed by [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) requests) the users will need to send these requests periodically and in this case you also need to introduce timers as real users don't hammer application non-stop, they at least need some time to "think" between operations or to simulate periodic [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) if they're "idle"

More information: [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers)

Comment: 'Stay logged in' here- means keep on creating the orders